# How to make a ruby command line application with pager?

Tags: ruby, command-line, pager

I'm making a command line tool using Ruby. It will print a lot of text on screen. Currently, I'm using shell pipeline (`may_app | more`) to do so. But I think it's better to has a default pager.

It's just like what you see when execute `git log` . One can disable pager by using `git --nopager log`.

I've done quite much google work and find one gem: [hirb](https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb) , but it seems a little overkill.

After many tries, I'm current using shell wrapper to do so:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# xray.rb is the core script
# doing the main logic and will
# output many rows of text on 
# screen
XRAY=$HOME/fdev-xray/xray.rb

if [ "--nopager" == "$1" ]; then
    shift
    $XRAY $*
else
    $XRAY $* | more
fi
```

It works. But is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it right. But instead using `more` you'd better get a pager from `$PAGER` environment variable, if any.

Some people prefer `less` to `more` for example, and others have their favorite parser options set in this var.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pipe in Ruby via a call to `system` and provide the options (along with a nice help interface) like so:

```
require 'optparse'

pager = ENV['PAGER'] || 'more'

option_parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on("--[no-]pager",
          "[don't] page output using #{pager} (default on)") do |use_pager|
    pager = nil unless use_pager
  end
end

option_parser.parse!

command = "cat #{ARGV[0]}"
command += " | #{pager}" unless pager.nil?
unless system(command)
  STDERR.puts "Problem running #{command}"
  exit 1
end
```

Now, you support `--pager` and `--no-pager` on the command line, which is nice to do.

Comment: This is different from what i want. I want to use pager out of `system` .

Comment: Not sure what this last comment means. This solution is pretty similar to the accepted one. The difference is that in one case you call ruby a bash script, and in the other you call a command from inside ruby. Depending on the context one is probably preferable but we don't have the full context. In both cases you get a runnable command which is able to pipe through a pager of choice or no pager at all.